# Using Rabin-Karp to search for multiple patterns in a string

Tags: algorithm, hash, language-agnostic, string-matching, rabin-karp

According to the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-Karp_string_search_algorithm) on Rabin-Karp string matching algorithm, it can be used to look for several different patterns in a string at the same time while still maintaining linear complexity. It is clear that this is easily done when all the patterns are of the same length, but I still don't get how we can preserve O(n) complexity when searching for patterns with differing length simultaneously. Can someone please shed some light on this?

Edit (December 2011):

The wikipedia article has since been updated and no longer claims to match multiple patterns of differing length in O(n).

Comment: It isn't the exact answer since it only deals with searching for one string at a time, not multiple, but there is some possibly useful information (under the heading 'Karp Rabin') that may help you at: http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/index.html

Comment: The wikipedia article claims it can find multiple patterns in O(n) time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the correct answer, but anyway:

**While constructing** the hash value, we can check for a match in the set of string hashes. Aka, the *current* hash value. The hash function/code is usually implemented as a loop and inside that loop we can insert our quick look up.
Of course, we must pick `m` to have the maximum string length from the set of strings.

**Update:** From Wikipedia,

```
[...]
for i from 1 to n-m+1
         if hs ∈ hsubs
             if s[i..i+m-1] = a substring with hash hs
                 return i
         hs := hash(s[i+1..i+m]) // <---- calculating current hash
[...]
```

We calculate *current* hash in `m` steps. On each step there is a *temporary* hash value that we can look up ( O(1) complexity ) in the set of hashes. All hashes will have the same size, ie 32 bit.

**Update 2:** an amortized (average) O(n) time complexity ?

Above I said that `m` must have the maximum string length. It turns out that we can exploit the opposite.
With [hashing for shifting substring search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-Karp%5Fstring%5Fsearch%5Falgorithm#Use_of_hashing_for_shifting_substring_search) and a fixed `m` size we can achieve O(n) complexity.
If we have variable length strings we can set `m` to the minimum string length. Additionally, in the set of hashes we don't associate a hash with the whole string but with the first m-characters of it.
Now, while searching the text we check if the current hash is in the hash set and we examine the associated strings for a match.
This technique will increase the false alarms but on average it has O(n) time complexity.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

As far as I can understand, you are suggesting keeping multiple hashes (one for each length of pattern) and using those to query a hashtable/BST. But, doesn't computing more than a constant number if hashes each iteration make the complexity more than  linear?

Comment: Thanks for explaining. But that is exactly the source of my confusion.
If we compute the current hash value in m steps, our overall complexity is no longer linear. It becomes O(n*m) (n is the length of the string, m is length of the longest pattern).

Comment: @MAK, O(n) is feasible if all strings are `m` size and we calc the hash as mentioned in section *Use of hashing for shifting substring search*. But for variable length strings, IMO, O(nm) is the best we can do with Rabin-Karp algorithm. Maybe that Wiki entry isn't clear.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that the wikipedia entry is simply wrong on this. It claims the complexity should be O(n+k). Thanks again.

Comment: @MAK, see update2. If I come up with a better solution, I'll post a new update.

Comment: @Nick D., Thank you very much. That solution is probably the correct O(n) algorithm (or very close). But suppose the smallest pattern length is 1 (i.e. single character pattern). That would still cause a very high rate false alarms if the input alphabet is small (e.g. 'A'-'Z'), probably enough to cause near O(nm) performance in practice. But thanks, this is a brilliant solution nonetheless.

Comment: @Nick D., Had a talk about this with a friend, he came up with an input case that causes this approach to fail. Try your algorithm against this: pattern 1: blah pattern 2: aaaabcd Text to search: aaaaaaaaaaa.........aa (all 'a's) That would still cause O(nm) performance.

Comment: I'm aware of such cases. That kind of data show off the worst part  of the algorithm. There is probably a way to minimize the false alarms but I haven't figured it out, yet.

Comment: note that even quicksort in the worst case makes Θ(n2) comparisons ;) (excuses, excuses, excuses)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the hash values of the substrings are related mathematically. Computing the hash *H(S,j)* (the hash of the characters starting from the jth position of string *S*) takes *O(m)* time on a string of length *m*. But once you have that, computing *H(S, j+1)* can be done in constant time, because *H(S, j+1)* can be expressed as a function of *H(S, j)*.

*O(m) + O(1) => O(m)*, i.e. linear time.

[Here's a link](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~ellard/Q-97/HTML/root/node43.html) where this is described in more detail (see e.g. the section "What makes Rabin-Karp fast?")

Comment: I get why Rabin-Karp is fast. I've used to before to find single patterns in a string. I'm trying to figure out how it can be used to find multiple patterns in a string simultaneously in O(n) time (as opposed to O(n*k) if you search for k patterns one by one).

Comment: @MAK: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Isn't the answer to that at the bottom of the wikipedia article? "In contrast, the variant Rabin-Karp above can find all k patterns in O(n+k) time in expectation, because a hash table checks whether a substring hash equals any of the pattern hashes in O(1) time." Creating the hash is O(k). Looking for a match in a hash table is an O(1) operation. If any match, you win.