# CLRS 32.2-2 - How to use Rabin-Karp to match k patterns of varying length at once?

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching

I've been trying to solve the following problem in CLRS:

> How can you extend the Rabin-Karp method to find k different patterns in a given text at once? At first assume all patterns have same length, then generalize to allow different length string patterns.

The easier case can be done by using a HashSet - by throwing hash of k patterns into it, and then using one pass through a given world, we can check in O(1) time, if the current hash is in the HashSet.

I'm wondering about generalizing it however. The best approach I found requires j passes through a text, where j is number of different pattern lengths (one pass for each length).

Can it be done better? I'm looking for a linear time solution (O(n+m) where m is size of all k patterns combined).

I saw [Using Rabin-Karp to search for multiple patterns in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318126/using-rabin-karp-to-search-for-multiple-patterns-in-a-string?rq=1), but there is no answer for different length patterns.

Comment: The only thing I could imagine is taking the minimum length of all patterns in the case where they are not too different in length. But you won't get any worst-case guarantees with that approach